# Custom error message when calling a function that doesn't exist in a class

Tags: php, function, class

I have a class on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/wdele/phplib))* and I would like to output a custom error message if the specified class doesn't exist. Is this possible? For example:

user tries to call function `123456()` and it doesn't exist (`main::123456()`) and it doesn't exist, output the error message:

> Sorry, the function 123456 does not exist or was removed.

Is this possible?

*link does no longer exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by overriding the magic method [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). When doing so you **must** provide two arguments for the method (eg., `$name` and `$args`) otherwise this won't work.

```
class MyClass {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        throw new Exception("failed to call method ".$name);
    }
    public function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        throw new Exception("failed to call static method ".$name);
    }
}
```